# Checking a 2-dimensional vector for specific patterns

Tags: c++, validation, dictionary, vector

So i have a little game which reads from a config_file and stores the information in an object of the Game-class.
This works fine so far. My only problem is the validation of the config_file.
For example:

```
G...grass
T...townhall

MAP:
GGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGTGGGG
GGGGGGGGGG
GGGGGGGGGG
```

After the line 'MAP:' i need to store every character into a two dimensional vector called map. This works fine.
Now i need to validate the map:
There can be one or more townhalls with minimum size 1x1 and the maximum size 3x3.
Townhalls can not be placed next to each other.

```
valid:
MAP:
GGGGGGTGGG
GGTTTGGGGT
GGTTTGGGGT
GGTTTGGGGT
GGGGGGTTGG

not valid:
MAP:
GGGGGGGGGG
GGTTTTGGGT
GGTTTGGGGT
GGTTTGGGTT
GGGGTTGGGG
```

I've been sitting in front of my PC for hours trying to figure that out. Is there a simple way to code it without writing hundreds of if-statements?
I am coding in c++.
Thanks!

Comment: Tip: If you can find one `T`, where can you go from there?

Comment: Are townhalls rectangular?

Comment: I am iterating with a for loop through the whole 2-dimensional vector. When I find a 'T', i am searching for the next 'T' near it. And this until i got the third 'T'. Then i go into the next row an check, whether there is a 'T' or not. And this goes on till the townhall is 3x3.
My Problem is what am I doing, if there is another townhall in the map?

Comment: The townhalls are rectangular yes

Comment: one method is check existence of 4 continuous `T`

Comment: Loop through all squares of the map. If you find a 'T', and there is no T in the square above or to the left of it then it is a top left corner of a townhall.
If it is top left corner then Check how many 'T' there are horizontally. Then check how many 'T' are vertically. Then you can check the whole rectangle is all T. Then check the squares around the townhall are not a 'T'. Keep a count of townhalls found.
Doesn't require hundreds of if-statements, but does require a few loops.

Comment: One trick to avoid bound checking is to surround the map with special value (G might do the job here) and just check for its internal, so neighbor necessary in bound.

Comment: @CraigR - I will try that, it will take a little bit of time i think.

Answer (score 0):

You might do something like that once surround the map:

```
std::size_t compute_width_of_town(const std::vector<std::string>& map,
                                  std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    std::size_t width;
    for (width = 0; map[x + width][y] == 'T'; ++width) {/* Empty */}
    return width;
}

std::size_t compute_height_of_town(const std::vector<std::string>& map,
                                   std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    std::size_t height;
    for (height = 0; map[x][y + height] == 'T'; ++height) {/* Empty */}
    return height;
}

bool validate_inside_town(const std::vector<std::string>& map,
                          std::size_t x, std::size_t y,
                          std::size_t width, std::size_t height)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != width; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j != height; ++j) {
            if (map[x + i][y + j] != 'T') {
                return false;   
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool validate_around_town(const std::vector<std::string>& map,
                          std::size_t x, std::size_t y,
                          std::size_t width, std::size_t height)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != width; ++i) {
        if (map[x + i][y - 1] == 'T'
            || map[x + i][y + height] == 'T') {
            return false;    
        }
    }
    for (std::size_t j = 0; j != height; ++j) {
        if (map[x - 1][y + j] == 'T'
            || map[x + width][y + j] == 'T') {
            return false;    
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool validate_town(const std::vector<std::string>& map,
                   std::size_t x, std::size_t y)
{
    const std::size_t width = compute_width_of_town(map, x, y);
    const std::size_t height = compute_height_of_town(map, x, y);

    return width <= 3
        && height <= 3
        && validate_inside_town(map, x, y, width, height)
        && validate_around_town(map, x, y, width, height);
}

bool validate_map(const std::vector<std::string>& map)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i != map.size() - 1; ++i) {
        for (std::size_t j = 1; j != map[i].size() - 1; ++j) {
            if (map[i][j] == 'T'
                && map[i - 1][j] != 'T'
                && map[i][j - 1] != 'T'
                && !validate_town(map, i, j))
            {
                return false;   
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and test it with something like:

```
std::cout << validate_map({
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "XGGGGGGTGGGX",
    "XGGTTTGGGGTX",
    "XGGTTTGGGGTX",
    "XGGTTTGGGGTX",
    "XGGGGGGTTGGX",
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    }) << std::endl;
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/SWUrba)